# Tag start is not closed

Tags: python, django

Tag start is not closed とエラーが出ました。

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{% static "images/{{photo.image}}"%}">
```

とhtmlファイルに書いたのですが...

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/
の公式ドキュメントの書き方を参考にしたので何が悪いのかわかりません。
どう直せば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`{% %}` の中に `{{ }}` が入ってるのが原因な気がします。
以下のどちらかのように書くとどうでしょうか？

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{% static 'images' %}/{{photo.image}}">
```

or

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{% static 'images/' + photo.image %}">
```